# Can I get the value from a typeahead.js field?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) for an autocomplete field. I need to get the value in the input regardless if is in the autocomplete list or not.

Is this possible?

How can I make this?

Could this be a new issue?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: You can't get it like this `$(yourselector).val()`

Comment: AFAIK you can only get the value catching the change event of the plugin.

Comment: I've checked [this](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadval) and don't works...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({/* typeahead options */})
.on("input", function(e) {
  // do stuff with current `typeahead` `value`
  var myVal = e.target.value; // `$(e.target).typeahead("val")
  console.log(myVal)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2reurafk/1/

See [jQuery#typeahead('val')](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadval)

Answer (score 1):

my solution for my code, wasnt easy to figure it out but thanks to @guest271314

```
$('form#prefetch').bind("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var query = $(e.target).typeahead("val").split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();
        return window.location = baseurl+'search/'+query;
    }
});
```